# ForEach loop in interrupting and joining threads

Tags: java, multithreading, foreach

Having an `ArrayList<Wheel>` wheels, being Wheel a class that extends **Thread**, what happens if I have the follow:

```
wheels.forEach(a -> {
                try{
                    a.interrupt();
                    a.join();
                }catch(InterruptedException exception){}
            });
```

What will be the instruction order from this code?

Right now I think it will go the following: 1)**a** is interrupted, 2)my *main* thread will join **a**, and **ONLY AFTER a** being finished will the forEach loop continue thru the remaing of the items, right?

Is it possible to do an iteration in the ArrayList where all the threads in it will be interrupted and joined, without doing it item by item manually?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: You could break it into 2 loops. One that interrupts the threads. Then a 2nd one to join each one.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp. Sute, but wouldn't it have the same problem? The second one would do the main wait, then wait, then wait again. Maybe I'm seeing this wrong, what I want is the threads to all join at "the same time" (not exactly obvisouly, but roughly) and have main wait only once.

Comment: Yes, but with 2 loops you first tell all the threads "time to quit" (practically) simultaneously in the 1st loop. So each thread starts shutting down _at the same time_. Then, in the 2nd loop, you `join` a, let's say that takes 4 seconds. Then you `join` b but b only took 2 seconds to shut down so b is already done when you try to `join` it and `join` returns right away. So the whole thing takes 4 seconds (the max time any of the threads needs to shut down), not 6 (the cumulative time of all the threads). I assume this is your goal.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes! That's it! Thank you for such a detailed answer :)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Although, it wasn't an *answer*, only a *comment*. If you put it in an *answer* people would be able to vote on it, accept it, etc. Hint, hint.

Comment: `a.join()` doesn't take any time if thread `a` already has terminated.

Comment: A `CountdownLatch` is another possibility if the intent is to wait for the well-behaved threads to finish before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Johnny's comment is correct for your current implementation. You could also follow another path like;

Instead of extending thread, you can implement Runnable(or Callable) in your Wheel class and submit your list of tasks to a executor service. This way you can get the benefits of thread pooling(reusing threads) and use the built in functionality of shutting down and waiting all threads to complete.

Example:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
wheels.foreach(wheel -> executor.submit(wheel));

//when you want to shutdown
executor.shutdownNow(); // this will send interrupt to thread pool threads.
executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
// block the current thread until executor finishes or timeout expires. 
// You could give a bigger timeout or call this with in a while loop to ensure 
// executor definitely finished.
// like this: while(!executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
```